# Cannot automount NFS share on Centos 7

Tags: linux, nfs, centos7, automount

I have a fresh install of Centos 7. I cannot seem to auto mount an NFS share located on `192.168.254.105:/srv/nfsshare` from the Centos client.

Mounting the share manually however, works perfectly.

**/etc/auto.master** has been commented out completely to simplify the problem, save for the following line:

```
/-       /etc/auto.nfsshare
```

**/etc/auto.nfsshare**  holds the following line:

```
/tests/nfsshare       -fstype=nfs,credentials=/etc/credentials.txt    192.168.254.105:/srv/nfsshare
```

**/etc/credentials.txt** holds:

```
 user=user
 password=password
```

The expected behavior is that when I `ls -l /tests/nfsshare`, I will see a few files that my fileserver's **/srv/nfsshare** directory holds.

It does not. Instead, it shows nothing.

The logs from **sudo journalctl --unit=autofs.service** shows this when it starts (debug enabled):

```
 Nov 20 00:25:38 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Starting Automounts filesystems on demand...
 Nov 20 00:25:38 localhost.localdomain automount[21204]: Starting automounter version 5.0.7-48.el7, master map auto.master
 Nov 20 00:25:38 localhost.localdomain automount[21204]: using kernel protocol version 5.02
 Nov 20 00:25:38 localhost.localdomain automount[21204]: lookup_nss_read_master: reading master files auto.master
 Nov 20 00:25:38 localhost.localdomain automount[21204]: parse_init: parse(sun): init gathered global options: (null)
 Nov 20 00:25:38 localhost.localdomain automount[21204]: spawn_mount: mtab link detected, passing -n to mount
 Nov 20 00:25:38 localhost.localdomain automount[21204]: spawn_umount: mtab link detected, passing -n to mount
 Nov 20 00:25:38 localhost.localdomain automount[21204]: lookup_read_master: lookup(file): read entry /-
 Nov 20 00:25:38 localhost.localdomain automount[21204]: master_do_mount: mounting /-
 Nov 20 00:25:38 localhost.localdomain automount[21204]: automount_path_to_fifo: fifo name /run/autofs.fifo--
 Nov 20 00:25:38 localhost.localdomain automount[21204]: lookup_nss_read_map: reading map file /etc/auto.nfsshare
 Nov 20 00:25:38 localhost.localdomain automount[21204]: parse_init: parse(sun): init gathered global options: (null)
 Nov 20 00:25:38 localhost.localdomain automount[21204]: spawn_mount: mtab link detected, passing -n to mount
 Nov 20 00:25:38 localhost.localdomain automount[21204]: spawn_umount: mtab link detected, passing -n to mount
 Nov 20 00:25:38 localhost.localdomain automount[21204]: mounted direct on /tests/nfsshare with timeout 300, freq 75 seconds
 Nov 20 00:25:38 localhost.localdomain automount[21204]: do_mount_autofs_direct: mounted trigger /tests/nfsshare
 Nov 20 00:25:38 localhost.localdomain automount[21204]: st_ready: st_ready(): state = 0 path /-
 Nov 20 00:25:38 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Started Automounts filesystems on demand.
```

The following appears in my logs when I attempt to force mounting of the nfs share via **ls -l /tests/nfsshare**:

```
 Nov 20 00:48:05 localhost.localdomain automount[22030]: handle_packet: type = 5
 Nov 20 00:48:05 localhost.localdomain automount[22030]: handle_packet_missing_direct: token 21, name /tests/nfsshare, request pid 22057
 Nov 20 00:48:05 localhost.localdomain automount[22030]: attempting to mount entry /tests/nfsshare
 Nov 20 00:48:05 localhost.localdomain automount[22030]: lookup_mount: lookup(file): looking up /tests/nfsshare
 Nov 20 00:48:05 localhost.localdomain automount[22030]: lookup_mount: lookup(file): /tests/nfsshare -> -fstype=nfs,credentials=/etc/credenti...fsshare
 Nov 20 00:48:05 localhost.localdomain automount[22030]: parse_mount: parse(sun): expanded entry: -fstype=nfs,credentials=/etc/credentials.tx...fsshare
 Nov 20 00:48:05 localhost.localdomain automount[22030]: parse_mount: parse(sun): gathered options: fstype=nfs,credentials=/etc/credentials.txt  
 Nov 20 00:48:05 localhost.localdomain automount[22030]: [90B blob data]
 Nov 20 00:48:05 localhost.localdomain automount[22030]: dev_ioctl_send_fail: token = 21
 Nov 20 00:48:05 localhost.localdomain automount[22030]: failed to mount /tests/nfsshare
 Nov 20 00:48:05 localhost.localdomain automount[22030]: handle_packet:      type = 5
 Nov 20 00:48:05 localhost.localdomain automount[22030]: handle_packet_missing_direct: token 22, name /tests/nfsshare, request pid 22057
 Nov 20 00:48:05 localhost.localdomain automount[22030]: dev_ioctl_send_fail: token = 22
```

Additionally, **ls -l /tests/nfsshare** actually produces the error:

```
 ls: cannot access nfsshare/: No such file or directory
```

How can I fix this issue? As stated before, manual mounting the share works fine.

Answer (score 1):

False @Abhinav Aggarwal

in /etc/auto.master file you can mount direct folders add /- instead /mnt/tests

'''
/-  /etc/auto.nfsshare
'''

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I believe the problem lies in the fact that the directory `/tests/nfsshare` exists, try:

- Removing it with `rm -r /tests/nfsshare`
- Then to force mounting `ls -la /tests/nfsshare`.

From this link [Redhat: 21.2.2. Mounting NFS File Systems using autofs](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/4/html/System_Administration_Guide/Mounting_NFS_File_Systems-Mounting_NFS_File_Systems_using_autofs.html) the target directory for autofs shouldn't exist because is created by automount.

Hope this helps.

Comment: /tests/nfsshare isn't existing when `autofs` isn't running :( when it is running though, it's listed as parts of `tests`, but doing an `ls -l on it` gives me the "no such directory" error.

Answer (score 0):

Autofs does not mount in direct folders for eg. we wish to mount the nfs path to /var/www/test.

/var/www containing other files. Hence, best solution to the problem is to map the path to separate folder and create the link to the relevant path.

create the path in the local machine

```
mkdir /mnt/tests/nfsshare
```

/etc/auto.master - make following entries to mount the nfs path.

```
/mnt/tests       /etc/auto.nfsshare
```

Make the following entry in the /etc/auto.nfsshare

```
nfsshare       -fstype=nfs,credentials=/etc/credentials.txt    192.168.254.105:/srv/nfsshare
```

create a link to the folder /mnt/tests/nfsshare

```
ln -s /mnt/tests/nfsshare /var/www/nfsshare
```